# Printing elements from a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of lists that is extracted from a data frame.

```
[[[1, 1, 'D'], [2, 5, 'C'], [6, 22, 'S'], [23, 57, 'C'], [151, 169, 'S'], [170, 173, 'C']],
 [[1, 1, 'D'], [2, 143, 'S'], [144, 145, 'C']]]
```

I am using a for loop to access each nested list within the bigger list as follows:

```
for value in my_list:
    each_nested_list = value
```

Which on each iteration the variable *each_nested_list* will hold the nested list, e.g.

```
each_nested_list = [[1, 1, 'D'], [2, 5, 'C'], [6, 22, 'S'], [23, 57, 'C'], [151, 169, 'S'], [170, 173, 'C']]
```

But I then want to access each list within the nested list *each_nested_list* by using an inner for loop in the above code, but when I print each the result it prints each individual character in the extracted list, like below:

```
[
[
1
,

1
,

'
D
'
]
,

[
2
,

5
,

'
C
'
]
,
...
```

**EDIT 1: Added nested for loop**

This is the nested for loop I am using:

```
for value in my_list:
    for x in value:
        print(x)
```

**EDIT 2: Added code for my_list**

```
my_list = testdf['Test_intervals']
```

*my_list* is just taking the column from the data frame.

[image: This is the column from the data frame I am extracting, 'Test_intervals']

Comment: Is it actually stored as lists, or as a string that looks like a list?

Comment: @G.Anderson I'm pretty sure it is stored as a list, I have tried using eval() on the list also, but no luck.

Comment: could you share the part of your code where you store the values in `my_list`?

Comment: @Declan Notice how it's printing the chars `[` and `]`. This is a sign that the list is in fact being stored as an `str` type. As @Arya11 and @G. Anderson suggested, you'll need to post the code for your `my_list` so we can debug it.

Comment: @Arya11 updated the question above

Comment: are you sure `my_list` is a list? you can check it by using `if type(my_list) is list: print('yes')`

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful:

```
each_nested_list = []
for value in my_list:
    for x in value:
        each_nested_list.append(x)

for obj in each_nested_list:
    for ob in obj:
        print(ob)
```

Comment: Thanks but this still produces the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you have strings in you DF so you can use:

```
from ast import literal_eval

for value in my_list:
    for x in literal_eval(value):
        for e in x:
            print(e)
```

to print the elemnents